# i want to store data to database from local storage object

Tags: typescript, angular7

I want to store my data to a database from the local storage object

comonent1.html

```
<form [formGroup]="Add" (ngSubmit)="Submit()">
 <select formControlName="control1">
        <option  value="Select">Select</option>                         
        <option  value="value1">value1</option>                         
        <option  value="value2">value2</option>                 
 </select>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

component1.ts

```
   Add= this.formbuilder.group({control1:[''])}

   Submit(){
   localStorage.setItem('form-data', JSON.stringify(this.Add.value));
   this.router.navigate(['/component2'])}
```

component2.ts

```
    Save(){
    let formValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form-data'))}
```

I don't know how to store data to database from local storage. I want to store dropdown by its id.

Comment: What is the database you are using? And what about the backend of the project?

Comment: I m using MySQL workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38195831/10574354) stack overflow question and answer.

Comment: You could send the data to your back-end (API) with [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) and update your database on your back-end.